# JAXB none optional collection

Tags: jaxb

I'm writing a JAXB entity.

```java
public class Person {

    public Collection<String> getNames() {
        if (names == null) {
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private int age;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    @XmlElementWrapper(required = true)
    private Collection<String> names;
}
```

Say we have following instance.

```java
final Person person = new Person();
person.setAge(18);
```

When I marshal this instance I got

```xml
<person>
  <age>18<age>
</person>
```

Which is not what I expected.

Only after I call `getNames()`, I could get

```xml
<person>
  <age>18</age>
  <games/>
<person>
```

Is this normal?

Comment: I'm currently solving this problem by providing `beforeMarshal(Marshaller)` method which calls `getGames` internally.

Comment: Oops, adding `nillable = true` on `@XmlElementWrapper` make the same solution. I think this is better.

Answer (score 1):

Set names to a new ArrayList in your constructor, or a static assignment in the field definition.

Comment: Thank you. I solved with `nillable = true` attribute on `@XmlElementWrapper`.